# Modigliani risk-adjusted performance - marginal contribution

Tags: risk-management

I would like to carry out risk-adjusted return attribution using the M^2 excess return, such that i can express

M^2 excess return = risk free rate + sharpe ratio x benchmark vol - benchmark return

in terms of

M^2 excess return = sum of w_i x MC_i

where MC_i is the marginal contribution and w_i = weight in portfolio - weight in benchmark

However, I am struggling to express M^2 in terms of w_i and my gut feeling is that this can't be done, but i wanted to check whether i was missing a trick here